# Docker container unable to receive external UDP (docker-compose)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, udp

I have a simple toy application that receives udp packets on port 8529 and logs them.

When I run it without using docker, it works fine.
However, when I run it using docker (with docker-compose & publishing the ports) it doesn't receive it.

What could be the reasons?

Here is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  udp-receiver:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./DockerFile
    ports:
      - "8529:8529/udp"
```